# Could not find OneSignal-4.6.4.aar (com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.6.4)

Tags: java, onesignal

please help me to solve this problem. I am having this error and have been trying to solve it but I couldn't.

Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find OneSignal-4.6.4.aar (com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.6.4).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/onesignal/OneSignal/4.6.4/OneSignal-4.6.4.aar

Comment: Can you add more detail on what you are trying to do, what code you are running etc? That way people have an easier time answering your question

Answer (score 1):

add         mavenCentral()
to buildscript and allprojects in your build.gradle (and then sync)
[image]